# How can I interpret JSON returned from jQuery.ajax and using a POST action?

Tags: jquery, json, post

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Services/MyService.asmx/Select",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{'data':'test'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(msg){ 
                alert(msg); 
             },
    error: function(xhr){ alert(xhr.statusText);}                
});
```

The call to the method returns the following:

```
"{"FirstName":"James"}"
```

When I get the value back, my alert returns the full json string.  If I try to do `alert(msg.FirstName)`, I get "undefined".

I have seen a lot of examples using the getJSON() method; however, I haven't seen a way to use that for a POST verb.  Can anyone point me in the right direction where I'm going wrong?  Based on the jquery documentation, the return value should be the same dataType (json) so I'm not certain what I'm missing.

EDIT:
I looked on my service and it is matching examples that I'm finding in terms of the method signature returning a string.  I've also confirmed the response type is of application/json.

EDIT2:
Updated the response to include the outside quotes.  I'm also using a custom JavaScriptConverter to do the JSON serialization.  The custom converter just takes my object properties (in this case FirstName) and loads it and it's value into a Dictionary collection which the ASP.Net AJAX Extensions v1.0 can serialize easily.

EDIT3:
Looking into the issue that I was having with eval() (it caused an `Expected ";"` error), I noticed that the json property names were also enclosed in quotes.  Once I removed the quotes from the property name (not the value), eval() worked again.  Looking into the server side of this issue now.

Comment: Once you get the escaping/quoting issue fixed, you shouldn't need the extra, manual eval().  jQuery does that for you automatically.

Comment: Sadly, with or without the escaping, I still needed the eval() statement.  I'm not a fan of it but it works and it's in the context of an anonymous function so I feel ok with using it until I can upgrade the client to .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery `.ajax` usage looks solid. How are you verifying the data returned? Firebug? Fiddler? Because `.asmx` webservices don't return data like `{"FirstName":"James"}`. Responses look more like:

```
{"d":{"FirstName":"James"}}
```

(See http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

For your `success` callback, try:

```
function(res) { alert(res.d.FirstName) }
```

---

**Edit**: Saw your updates and comment re v1.0 of the ASP.Net AJAX:

I'm not positive how v1.0 works wrt serializing your response, but my guess is if you're doing your own custom JSON serialization in your WebService method, the response may be getting JSON serialized *again*. So you're serializing twice.

I believe all the components you're using are doing what they're supposed to, it's just now your `success` callback needs to unserialize manually since you're serializing manually on the server:

```
function(res) {
    res = eval('(' + res + ')');
    alert(res.FirstName);
}
```

Comment: I ran into this same problem before.

Comment: ASMX Services only return the .d property under the MS ASP.Net AJAX 3.5.  My client hasn't upgraded to the 3.5 framework at all yet so I'm stucking using v1.0 of the ASP.Net AJAX extensions which didn't include it.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC you can eval the string, and the result will be the json object.

myJSON = eval(jsonString);

Comment: Why I attempt to use eval, it's giving me the error `Expected ';'`.  I'm looking into why that's not working.

Comment: Aha, crescentfresh above me added the caveat I forgot - surround with parentheses, for some reason javascript gets confused if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your post variables with a JSON object as the second parameter.

Example:

```
$.getJSON("service.py",
    { foo: bar },
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() { // blah });
    }
);
```

---

EDIT: I see what you mean now.  Does your service return "something/json" as the MIME type?  If you're looking at the response headers in Firebug, it should look something like this:

```
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: The code you provided still using a HTTP GET verb to the server method.  I need a HTTP POST.  The service.py file in your example would be retrieved via a http get regardless of the data in the 2nd parameter.  This will not work for me sadly.

Comment: The response content-Type is coming back from the service as application/json.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$getJSON` with ASMX services serialized through `System.Web.Extensions`.  You're making the call correctly with `$.ajax()`.

Have you tried using Firebug to set a breakpoint inside the success handler and inspecting the *msg* value?

Comment: When I set a breakpoint in firebug and look at the value of msg, I get the following verbatum `"{"FirstName":"James"}"`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
 result = eval('(' + result.d + ')');
```